# How to install php7.2 on Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, php

I have a problem to install php.
I have tested a lot of solutions, but without success.

I'm using Debian 8 server.

Here is the error in French (sorry).
In English this error is about "break package of php":

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont   pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
php : Dépend: php7.2 mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».


root@vps504782:~# aptitude show php
Paquet : php                                       
Version :          
1:7.2+61+0~20180412074047.7
+stretch~1.g.  bp7c9031
État: non installé
Priorité : optionnel
Section : php
Responsable : Debian PHP Maintainers     
<pkg-php-maint
@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture : all
Taille décompressée : 12,3 k
Dépend: php7.2
Fourni par : php5.6
(5.6.36-1+0~20180505045928.13
+stretch~1             .gbp9b5cab), php5.6
         (5.6.36-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)             , php7.0 (7.0.10-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.11-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.12-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.13-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.14-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.15-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.16-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.17-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.18-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.19-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.20-1~dotdeb+8.2), php7.0
         (7.0.22-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.23-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.24-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.25-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.26-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.26-1~dotdeb+8.2), php7.0
         (7.0.27-0+deb9u1), php7.0
         (7.0.27-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.28-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.29-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.30-1+0~20180505045735.18+stretch~1             .gbpcfecb9), php7.0
         (7.0.30-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)             , php7.0 (7.0.30-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.8-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.0
         (7.0.9-1~dotdeb+8.1), php7.1
         (7.1.17-1+0~20180505045738.17+stretch~1             .gbpde69c6), php7.1
         (7.1.17-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)             , php7.2
         (7.2.5-1+0~20180505045740.21+stretch~1.             gbpca2fa6), php7.2
         (7.2.5-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)
Description : server-side, HTML-. 
embedded scripting language (default)
PHP (recursive acronym for PHP:   
Hypertext
Preprocessor) is a widely-used open   
source
general-purpose scripting language that is
especially suited for web development and    
can be
embedded into HTML. 

This package is a dependency package,    
which depends on latest stable PHP  
version (currently 7.2).

uname -a
Linux vps504782 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP   
Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07)  
x86_64 GNU/Linux


root@vps504782:~# apt-cache policy php
php:
  Installé : (aucun)
  Candidat : 
1:7.2+61+0~20180412074047.7
+stretch~1.gbp7c9031
 Table de version :. 
1:7.2+61+0~20180412074047.7
+stretch~1.gbp7c9031 500
    500 https://packages.sury.org/php   
stretch/main amd64 Packages
  1:7.2+60+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     
500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/. 
php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
 1:7.0+49 500
    500 http://deb.debian.org/debian   
stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please provide information about repository you try to use for this installation or source from which you download this package. Php 7.2 is not available in default debian repository for release 8: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=jessie&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php5

Comment: Welcome to U&L , Did you need to install php7.2 on debian jessie?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: I have edit post, yes I need it but I cant :c

Comment: Can you add `apt-cache policy php` , please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dotdeb urls (`http://packages.dotdeb.org`) from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory then run:

```
apt update
apt -f install
```

To install php7.2 on debian Stretch  (or Debian Jessie) you should use the [Ondřej Surý](https://deb.sury.org/) repository:

```
apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
apt update
```

Check the available php versions:

```
apt-cache search php7
```

To install php7.2:

```
apt install php7.2
```

Comment: http://packages.dotdeb.org do not appear in source list (tanks for your answer)

Comment: I have error when I execute apt-update                                 The following signatures could not be verified because of the public Key is not available - NO_PUBKEY

Comment: @therapha361 use `wget` answer edited. Commands should be executed as root or using `sudo`.

Comment: @therapha361 Please do not forget to add the output of `apt-cache policy php` to you question.

Comment: It was edited and answer do not work

Comment: I am too happy. I have succeeded, I put you as an answer you put me on the way. I had to successfully delete the contents of the folder sources.list.d